# How to add empty startkey array index in couchDB view?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

Currently I'm using hyperledger fabric with couchDB container. I have a CouchDB view :

```js
  function (doc) {
    if(doc.groups.length > 0) {
      doc.groups.forEach(function (tag) {
        emit([doc.id, tag.fname, tag.lname, tag.no], tag);    
      });
    }
  }
```

I want to filter data using the start & end keys.

Can we use an **empty index** in startkey array for filter on view?

Here is example for the same:

```
http://0.0.0.0:7984/mychannel_team/_design/team_view/_view/team_view_filter
?skip=0&limit=21&reduce=false&startkey=[1,"isha",{},"45"]&endkey=[1,"isha",{},"45"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by querying the view with `startkey=[""]`.  One could use `null` too  ([3.2.2.5. Collation Specification](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#collation-specification)).

Do note the parameters

`startkey=[1,"isha",{},"45"]&endkey=[1,"isha",{},"45"]`

is poorly constructed in the sense that the use of `{}` seems to imply a wildcard, which is does not.

These parameters are equivalent to the prior

`startkey=[1,"isha",{}]&endkey=[1,"isha",{}]`

Because any field value following `{}` is ignored. Think of `{}` as a match-all, not a field/placeholder wildcard.

As another matter: regarding the OP's map function, the first field of the complex key will always be `null`.  It is probable the intention is to emit `doc._id` rather than `doc.id`.

Comment: Thanks for reply @RamblinRose. But I want to filter using the only tag.fname & tag.no value which is an index of 1&3. Then how can set the start& end key for the same?